# SQL show trips from date with drivers less than hire date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Learning, be kind.

More of interest to know if I am doing this correctly...
I need this to display trips with an Effective Date in 2005 made by Operators with less than three years on the job.  Is this the way to go about that?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TripID, t.*
FROM Trips AS t, Runs AS r JOIN Operators AS o
ON r.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
WHERE t.EffectiveDate >= '01/01/2005' AND t.EffectiveDate <= '12/31/2005' 
AND o.HireDate <= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, '2005') AND t.ScheduleID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: 1st, I question the cross join you use between Trips and Runs. You could get more help if you would provide table definitions for all 3 tables. 2nd, what is the business rule that determines the years experience of an Operator? Is it calculated based on January 1? Would an Operator who hit 3 years experience in the middle of the year qualify for your query?

Comment: By table definitions I meant for you to post at minimum the columns that serve as FKs to the 3 tables involved in this query (Trips, Runs, Operators) so that I can address your cross join (FROM Trips AS t, Runs AS r).

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server/TSQL, so I added that tag.  I also note that the use of commas in the `from` clause has been outdated for about two decades.  Learn to use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: I think what @Jax is trying to ask is how does Trips join to runs? Nothing in your question shows this join

Comment: Operators:  PK OperatorID
Trips:  fkTripsSchedules FOREIGN KEY (ScheduleID)
Runs:  PK RunID

Comment: So Trips has a scheduleID, so how does runs join to Schedule?

Comment: I'm still not getting what I need to help you out. Would it be possible for you to post your create table statements for all 3 tables involved in your query, complete with FK constraints? That might be easier. You could remove any non-relevant columns and constraints for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT
  t.TripID,
  t.RouteNumber,        
  t.StartLocation,      
  t.StartTime,          
  t.EndLocation,        
  t.EndTime,            
  t.EffectiveDate
FROM
  Trips AS t
  JOIN Schedules AS s 
    ON t.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
  JOIN Runs AS r
    ON s.RunID = r.RunID
  JOIN Operators AS o
    ON r.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
WHERE
  t.EffectiveDate BETWEEN '01/01/2005'  AND  '12/31/2005'
  AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, o.HireDate, t.EffectiveDate) < 36 -- Less than 3 years experience
```

Comment: Looks right to me. I was about to post the same answer.